# LISP: lisp overflowing problem from Hanoi tower problem

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
;gnu clisp 2.49

(defun hanoi(n from_tower to_tower aux_tower)
    (hanoi (- n 1) from_tower aux_tower to_tower)
    (hanoi (- n 1) aux_tower to_tower from_tower)
)

(print "n=3")
(hanoi 3 1 3 2)
```

I'm trying to make a Hanoi tower with 5 disks and compiling it on an online LISP compiler and it gave me this...

**Error(s), warning(s): - Lisp stack overflow. RESET**

I thought it was just a simple code but I can't find which part is getting overflowed.

Comment: What's preventing `n` from going negative in your code?

Answer (score 2):

There is no termination condition in your function.

Try executing by hand:

- `(hanoi 3 'a 'b 'c)`

  - calls `(hanoi 2 'a 'b 'c)` which

    - calls `(hanoi 1 'a 'c 'b)` which

      - calls `(hanoi 0 'a 'b 'c)` which

        - calls `(hanoi -1 'a 'c 'b)` which

          - calls `(hanoi -2 'a 'b 'c)` which

            - calls `(hanoi -3 'a 'c 'b)` and so on and so on until the stack of the poor Lisp interpreter overflows.